# how to add class on click event on another list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Problem is following. So, I have this HTML

```
<div class="sitemap">
   <div class="collapse-all">
      [<a href="#">alles Ausklappen / Einklappen</a>]
   </div>
<div class="collapse-list">    <!-- 1. box -->
  <div class="collapse-box">
     <h2>
        <a href="#first-select-box" title="" class="collapse-btn accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">Logo</a>
     </h2>
     <!-- This "in" class for some reason helps us to keep all  boxes closed -->
     <div class="collpase-container collapse in" id="first-select-box">
      <ul>
       <li >
```

And I need to add class, lets say "active" to an element collapse-box when user clicks on div "collapse-all". I hope I made it clear.

Here is small screenshot from DOM.

LINK TO screenshot:
http://i62.tinypic.com/r8e8zs.jpg

pls try to edit this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ufe8n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(".collapse-all a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".collapse-all").next().find('.collapse-box').addClass('active');
});
```

#### [Is this you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/ufe8n/2/)

Comment: @NinjaKornjaca you have not selected jQuery from top left **framework and extensions** ddls. checkout the fiddle i posted in the answer.

Comment: but, right now there is allways this active class insted to appear only when I click on collapse-all?? do you know hwy is that?

Comment: @Ninjakornjaca what do you mean by this? also you wanted this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in click handler of `.collapse-all` div:

```
$(".collapse-all").click(function(){
  $(this).next().find('.collapse-box').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".collapse-all").click(function(){
  $(".collapse-box").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: I've tried but this does not work. Could you pls show in jfidddle:http://jsfiddle.net/ufe8n/1/

Comment: @Ninjakornjaca You forgot to switch on JQuery in your fiddle. Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/ufe8n/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".collapse-all").live("click",function(){
  $(".collapse-box").addClass("active");
});
```